# About: java.lang.ArrayndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: java

I'm having some difficulties finding a solution for this error. I can't seem to figure out why. By the way, I'm new to programming.

```
public class Player{
private Map map;
private Image player2;
private double x;
private double y;
private double deltaX = 250;
private double deltaY = 250;    
private int width;
private int height;

public Player(){    
    player2 = new ImageIcon("C://images//ball.PNG").getImage();
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    deltaX = 100;
    deltaY = 100;           
}

public void movePlayer(long delta){
    map = new Map();    

     if(x > width){
       x = width;
       //vertical = true;
       deltaX =  -deltaX;           
    }else if(x < 0){
       x = 0;
       deltaX = -deltaX;
    }

    else{
       x += (delta * deltaX) / 1000;
    }   

    //This one can't execute properly 
    if(map.getMap(x, y)) {
        System.out.println("Collided");
    }else{

    }   
}   

public void draw(Graphics2D g){

    g.drawImage(player2, (int)x,  (int)y, null);
}
```

}

This is the Map class:

```
public class Map{
private Image tile1;
private int map[][] = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
             {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
             {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
             {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
             {1, 1, 1, 1, 0},               
        };

public Map(){
    tile1 = new ImageIcon("C://images//tile1.PNG").getImage();      

}

public boolean getMap(double x, double y){      
    return map[(int)x][(int)y] == 0;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g){
    for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
       for(int y = 0; y < map.length; y++){
           if(map[x][y] == 0)
             g.drawImage(tile1, x*33, y*33, null);          
       }
    }
}
```

}

I hope someone could point out where I'm doing wrong... Thanks

Comment: Attach stack trace, and, if possible, line numbers.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: You probably call getMap with values of x or y which are either > 4 or < 0... Can you check the value of x and y before the line `if(map.getMap(x, y)) {`?

Comment: @assylias, this is not a homework but a dummy code. I trying to get the the solution for this, get the logic and apply it to what I doing. Anyway, thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 1):

There is no check, `>=0 && <= 4`, of the `x` and `y` arguments in this call:

```
if(map.getMap(x, y)) {
```

You need to ensure that both `x` and `y` are legal indexes into the `map` array.

Note, that because `map` is a multi-dimensional array of `[5][5]` that the following `for` loop is *correct*:

```
for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < map.length; y++){
```

the inner `for` loop should use the length of the row being processed:

```
for(int x = 0; x < map.length; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < map[x].length; y++){
                        //^^^
```

otherwise a future change in the dimensions of the array could result in an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Hi, guys! Thank for your input. What I did (as you suggested), was to check the location of my x and y. Since my x and y are declared double I tried to divide the x and y value with the value of the image size:    <pre><code>if(map.getMap(x/33, y/33) == 0 ) { System.out.println("Collided"); }else{} this works, but I still have to make some adjustments with the location of my characters x and y. I'll be updating this post.